# Display number of days between 2 datepicker dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am looking to try and calculate the number of days between 2 datepicker fields and display that value in an input field. I have searched a lot of different methods but can't seem to get any to work. I am using boostrap-datepicker.js

I have created a JS fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/KLpq7/201/ so you can see my effort so far

My JS Is as follows

```
function days() {
        var a = $("#datepicker_start").datepicker('getDate').getTime(),
            b = $("#datepicker_end").datepicker('getDate').getTime(),
            c = 24*60*60*1000,
            diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((a - b)/(c)));
        $("#totaldays").val(diffDays)
}

$('.datepicker')
.datepicker({format: 'DD, dd.mm.yyyy'})
.on('changeDate', function(ev){
$(this).datepicker('hide').blur();
});
```

In the first part I am trying to achieve this, but it is not working!

Looking for some help...

Comment: Might be useful if you called the `days` function somewhere

Comment: any reference on how to do that?

Comment: @Redwall not sure if that is the problem but he means just calling the function like this: ´days();´

Comment: @Redwall: in your `changeDate` event just add `days();`... then you can work on the next problem (check the console)

Comment: @musefan, thanks man...I am brutally bad at JS as I am still learning, is there any chance you could help me further by editing the JSFiddle I made above to point me in the right direction...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have modified your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Deif/KLpq7/211/) that correctly calculates the differences. One think I noticed is that you use the `dd/mm/yyyy` format and by default JS wants the dates as `mm/dd/yyyy`. It is best if you handle it the 'American' way for date difference calculations, but if you must use the 'correct' style of `dd/mm/yyyy` then I would recommend taking a look at the [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) library.

Comment: cheers man, thanks a lot! Noted on the date, no problem...One last thing I was wondering was if it is possible to remove the weekends (sat, sun) from this calculation of days..

Comment: Not with your initial calculation. That's another question altogether, but it's mainly down to maths. You'd have to work out how many weeks have passed and then take 2 days from each week. Now it's working you should be able to play about with it.

Comment: cool deal man, thanks for the dig out! Will post that up in another question soon...

Answer (score 0):

```
function DateDiff(var date1, var date2) {
    return date1 - date2;
}
```

Should work if you pass in two Date objects in Javascript. The result returned will be the number of milliseconds between the two, which can be quite easily converted to days or hours or weeks, etc.

Comment: I think OP has that logic already done, they just need to work out how to call it correctly